# Codename one Layered Layout not fill the screen

Tags: layout, codenameone, layer

I implemented floating button with this thread : [How to achieve Floating Action Button in Codenameone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345381/how-to-achieve-floating-action-button-in-codenameone)
but I have an layout issue. THe content doesn want to fill the screen. Here the screenshot :
[image]

Here how I created the content :

```
final Container paneContainer = new Container(new LayeredLayout());

private Container getBottomContainer(Form parent) {
                newsfeedContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                newsfeedContainer.setScrollableY(true);
                loadData();
                newsfeedContainer.addPullToRefresh(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        loadData();
                    }
                });
                //newsfeedContainer.add(new Button("Button")).add(new Button("Button")).add(new Button("Button")).add(new Button("Button")).add(new Button("Button"));
                return newsfeedContainer;
            }

    private Container getUpperContainer(Form par) {
            FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(Component.RIGHT);
            flow.setValign(Component.BOTTOM);
            Container conUpper = new Container(flow);
            Button plus = new Button();
            FontImage.setMaterialIcon(plus, FontImage.MATERIAL_ADD, 5);
            plus.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
                Form f = new PostComment().commentForm(parent);
                f.getToolbar().setBackCommand(parent.getTitle(), BACK_POLICY, e -> parent.showBack());
                f.show();
            });
            conUpper.addComponent(plus);
            conUpper.setScrollableX(false);
            conUpper.setScrollableY(false);
            return conUpper;
        }

    public Container getContainer(Form parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
            paneContainer.setScrollableY(false);
            paneContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.center(getBottomContainer(parent)));
            paneContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.south(getUpperContainer(parent)));
            return paneContainer;
        }
```

How to make the container fill the screen and make the 'plus' button in the bottom right properly?

Comment: FYI https://www.codenameone.com/blog/floating-button.html

Comment: Hi @ShaiAlmog didn't realise if C1 have ootb floating button. Thanks for this implementation, will try to implement it.

Comment: It's new we just announced it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your Form BorderLayout and place the paneContainer in the center